# removing duplicates in SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas, duplicates

I have data that looks somewhat like this:

```
A        B        C

1        X        0.5
1        X        0.6
1        X        0.7
1        Y        100
1        Y        101
2        X        0.4
...
```

I want to remove the duplicates so that the data looks like:

```
A        B        C

1        X        0.5
1        Y        100
2        X        0.4
...
```

Can anyone help please? I have tried using `sort` and `sql` but it did not work.

Comment: Show what you tried.  Both `proc sort` and `proc sql` could give you the right result here.  Also, do you care which record is preserved in each set of A/B duplicates?  Specifically the first record (lowest by C)?

Comment: Look into `proc sort` with the `nodupkey` parameter.

Comment: Since this is EG you should also specify if you're using code or a task

Answer (score 1):

Try SORT again. In EG look at the SORT Task. There should be an option to select unique key and or unique observations.Your keys appear to be A/B.